# No Data beyond 1:2290 with Openlayers Plugin

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

No Data beyond scale 1:2,290 with Openlayers Plugin. I have not installed the plugin that you should deinstall to fix the problem: [Unable to zoom beyond scale of 1:2,256 in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111243/unable-to-zoom-beyond-scale-of-12-256-in-qgis)

How can I fix this?

Comment: The answer also recommends to install all other plugins, in case it is caused by another one. This could be annoying, but worth a shot. Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried this, but thats no solution. The same like before.